# Is there a way to change gedit encoding from UI?

Tags: gedit, text-editor, text, encoding

I have a txt file that came to me from windows
Gedit can't read it properly (cyrillic became garbage)

So far I haven't found a way to make gedit read it by changing something from UI
Gedit itself has only spelling highlight, right click -> properties doesn't have anything like that either

Is that possible? If not, how do I read the file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Go to **Save as**. Ctrl+shift+s will do.

A menu at the bottom **left** shows the charachter encoding.

Click to that, there's an option Add or remove.

A windows appears with a list of character encodings at the left and plus button to add.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a great tip. Remove all except UTF-8 will avoid opening in other encodings if something wrong with the file detection.